# error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'char' in assignment

Tags: c++, binary, char, int, bitset

When I am compiling this code, I always get this error. Here dna is set to char. I want the bit value in the bitset to be converted to a char and the char to a int. If this is not the right way, please guide.

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < myString.size(); ++i)  
{
    std::bitset<8> y(myString[i]);

    dna = y.to_string<char>();
    binary = dna;
    cout << binary << " ";
    while ( binary >= 10) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i) { // loops length of array
            a[i] = binary % 10;
            binary = binary / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line produces an error?

Comment: What is the type of the `dna` and `binary` variables?

Comment: binary is int and dna is char. the 5th line produces the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y.to_string();` returns `std::string`. It can't be converted to `char`.

Use this:

```
std::string dna = y.to_string();
unsigned long binary = y.to_ulong();
```

Comment: But I want to use the binary data and not the integral value of the binary

Comment: Oh! I understand now what you want. I updated my answer.

Comment: And is there a way to change the string to an int data type variable (the dna string)

Comment: @user3475283 Why do you want it? It's more efficient to convert a bitset to string and to integer than to convert a string to and integer or an integer to a string.

Comment: Why do people up vote even if you ask them not to do it?

Comment: If u are interested there is another question I have posted just now.