# Output not as expected from the array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, io, binary

I am writing a code where I take user user text input, convert it to binary, store each binary character in an element in an array and then print `A` or `T` for `0` and `G` or `C` for `1` at random. But the `ATGC` seem to not follow this rule and they come at random for every digit; 0 and 1. So If the binary is `0010101` I need output as `ATGACTG`. Also when I store the binary in an int variable, the zero in front of it vanishes. Is there a way to keep it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int p, i=0, a[100000];
    int s;
    string myString;
    int binary;

    cout << "Type your text: ";
    std::getline (std::cin,myString);
    for (std::size_t k=0; k < myString.size(); ++k)
    {
        std::bitset<8> y(myString[k]);

        std::string dna = y.to_string();
        binary = atoi(dna.c_str());
        cout << binary;
        while (binary != 0)
        {
            a[i] = binary % 10;
            binary = binary / 10;
            i++;
        }
    } 
    std::cout << std::endl;
    srand(time(0));
    for (int j = (i-1); j>-1; j--)
    {
        if (a[j] == 0)
        {
            p = rand() %2;
            if (p==0)
                cout<< "A";
            else
                cout<< "T";
        }
        if (a[j] == 1)
        {
            s = rand() %2;
            if (s == 0)
                cout<< "G";
            else
                cout<< "C";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation, please?

Comment: Try running in a debugger, and step through the code line by line. That should help you narrow down the location of your problem(s).

Comment: The Binary output is fine

Comment: I think the problem is coming from somewhere after the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [told](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33415557/5420829) you not to convert the string to an integer. You didn't listen. This is why leading 0 vanishes.

Your output seams to be completely random because you reverse the order of characters in the sequence when reading the information from `a`.

Here is how I'd solve your problem: [run online](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/J9RGK28a8hFsVO69)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Type your text: " << std::endl;
    std::string in_str;
    std::getline(std::cin, in_str);

    std::string binary_str;

    for(int i = 0; i < in_str.size(); ++i)
    {
        char c = in_str.at(i);
        binary_str.append(std::bitset<8>(c).to_string());
    }

    std::cout << binary_str << std::endl;

    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < binary_str.size(); ++i)
    {
        char c = binary_str.at(i);
        if(c == '0')
            std::cout << (rand() % 2 ? "T" : "A");
        else
            std::cout << (rand() % 2 ? "C" : "G");
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If you have any questions, ask me in the comments.

Edit: the OP asked me to explain all mistakes in his program.

## Where did all those zeros gone?

To answer this question I'll have to explain all things your program does line-by-line.

Here you convert a symbol to a bitset:

```
std::bitset<8> y(myString[k])
```

For example: if `k` is 'a', then the `y` would be 01100001.

Here you convert the bitset to a string:

```
std::string dna = y.to_string();
```

In our example the `dna` would be "01100001".

Here you convert the string to an integer:

```
binary = atoi(dna.c_str());
```

A very simplified version of what `atoi` does:

```
binary = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < dna.size(); ++i)
    binary = binary * 10 + (dna.at(i) - '0')
```

In our example the `binary` would be 1100001.

Note: that's NOT where you loose zeros. At this point you are still able to extract them because you know that you need to extract 8 digits. So you can append leading zeros to up it's length to 8.

The next line is where you actually loose zeros the first time because `cout` doesn't know that you want to print 8 digits.

```
cout << binary;
```

In our example it would print 1100001.

And here you loose zeros again because you stop extracting digits as soon as binary == 0 even if you extracted less than 8 digits. Also note that you are actually reversing what the function `atoi` just did with the only difference that you don't get your leading zeros back and the reverse order of bits (see the next paragraph):

```
while (binary != 0)
{
    a[i] = binary % 10;
    binary = binary / 10;
    i++;
}
```

## Why the output is "random"?

Here you are iterating through myString in the standard order

```
for (std::size_t k=0; k < myString.size(); ++k)
```

e.g. if myString is "abc" than
in the first iteration myString[k] would be 'a'
in the second iteration myString[k] would be 'b'
in the third iteration myString[k] would be 'c':

But in this loop you extract digits in reverse order:

```
while (binary != 0)
{
    a[i] = binary % 10;
    binary = binary / 10;
    i++;
}
```

eg if `binary` is 1100001
in the 1st iteration you extract 1 and `binary` becomes 110000
in the 2nd iteration you extract 0 and `binary` becomes 11000
in the 3rd iteration you extract 0 and `binary` becomes 1100
in the 4th iteration you extract 0 and `binary` becomes 110
in the 5th iteration you extract 0 and `binary` becomes 11
in the 6th iteration you extract 1 and `binary` becomes 1
in the 7th iteration you extract 1 and `binary` becomes 0

Now you end up with an array where bits inside a character code are reversed, but different characters are stored in the array in the normal order.

e.g. If the input string was "abc", then `a` would become:

```
1,0,0,0,0,1,1,  0,1,0,0,0,1,1,  1,1,0,0,0,1,1
 reversed 'a'    reversed 'b'    reversed 'c'
```

If you iterate through `a` in normal order, the order of bits inside character codes would be reversed. If you iterate through `a` in reverse order, you get the reversed order of characters.

As a rule of thumb: don't program by guessing, program by thinking.

## Further reading

[The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Most of this aphorisms are applicable to every programming language with the exception of [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)

[Raw C arrays are evil](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#arrays-are-evil)

Comment: I need it in int because I need to perform arithmetical operation on it to store each digit as an element in the array.

Comment: I already tried the backwards logic. It was completely random

Comment: @user3475283 It seams like you are asking for a detailed explanation of **every** mistake in your program.

Comment: @user3475283 Since C++11 is disabled in your compiler, I'll downgrade my code to an earlier version of C++. P.S. If I were you I'd google how to enable C++11.

Comment: @user3475283 I downgraded my code to C++03. Try compiling it again.

Comment: Thanks it works...so what was actually the problem...i mean why was the ATGC output at random?

Comment: @user3475283 I added a detailed explanation you asked for. I didn't mention the allocation of a megabyte-sized array on the stack and a missing bounds check in order to not make this wall of text even bigger.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why exactly you wrote so much wrong code, but I've managed to extract (and change) the code that actually does the job.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, a[8];
    std::string myString;

    std::cout << "Type your text: " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, myString);

    for(auto x : std::bitset<8>(myString).to_string())
        a[i++] = x == '1';

    std::cout << std::endl;
    srand(time(0));

    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        if(a[j] == 0)
            std::cout << (rand() % 2 ? "T" : "A");
        else if(a[j] == 1)
            std::cout << (rand() % 2 ? "C" : "G");

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And here's neater version of `main`:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a; // using std::vector
    std::bitset<8> bs;

    std::cout << "Type your text: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> bs; // std::bitset can be read from stream via operator>>

    for(auto x : bs.to_string())
        a.push_back(x == '1');

    std::cout << std::endl;
    srand(time(0));

    for(auto x : a)
        if(x == 0)
            std::cout << (rand() % 2 ? "T" : "A");
        else if(x == 1)
            std::cout << (rand() % 2 ? "C" : "G");

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Just ask if you want an explanation on some specific part.

Comment: Your code only extracts the first character of the input string. That's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm extracting one `std::bitset`.

Comment: `..\DNA.cpp:19:9: warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
     for(auto x : std::bitset<8>(myString).to_string())
         ^
..\DNA.cpp:19:14: error: 'x' does not name a type
     for(auto x : std::bitset<8>(myString).to_string())
              ^
`I get this error now

Comment: And yeah I need to do this for every character

Comment: That is because your compiler doesn't support C++11, try the code from the other answer.

Comment: BTW Where did you get `srand` and `rand`? I don't see `#include <cstdlib>`. P.S. I know it compiles, but it's not guarantied to. Or is it?

Comment: I'm using VS and `iostream`, `string` and `bitset` all include `cstdlib`. Same with GCC on Coliru. But I don't really know...